# Soap does not cast response fields to into typed objects

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl

I am a SOAP newb assigned to resurrecting an old soap interface. I've ported the soap service onto a new tomcat at a new path (and left the client unchanged).  I send the request:
  **http://myserver:8181/soap/SoapTest?wsdl**
and I get back:

```
  <wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.mycompany.com"
    xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/http"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.mycompany.com/SoapTest"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    name="SoapTestService" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.mycompany.com/SoapTest">

    <wsdl:import location="http://myserver:8181/soap/SoapTest?wsdl=SoapTest.wsdl"
          namespace="http://webservices.mycompany.com"></wsdl:import>
    <wsdl:binding name="SoapTestServiceSoapBinding" type="ns1:SoapTest">...</wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="SoapTestService">...</wsdl:service>
  </wsdl:definitions>
```

Seems promising.  A request to the import location **SoapTest?wsdl=SoapTest.wsdl** returns:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:ns1="http://webservices.mycompany.com"
  xmlns:ns2="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  name="SoapTest"
  targetNamespace="http://webservices.mycompany.com">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://webservices.mycompany.com"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      targetNamespace="http://webservices.mycompany.com" version="1.0">
    <xs:complexType name="sessionObj">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="code" type="xs:int"/>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="role" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="username" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    ... (and so on)
```

So the client can receive member xs name:type associations but seems not to be - or not to be applying them.  That is ...

*HUH.. upon review, I see xs being used as a namespace but xmlns:xsd defined??  How might this happen?*

ZSI client queries (from Windows, if that makes any difference) to this interface (Linux) receive responses containing the expected data payload but then map each data item into an individual "property" - resulting in a list of generic properties.

I was expecting a list of typed members, with each property cast to its xs type (e.g. int, long, string, string for the above), right?

Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: Given the amount of information provided here, I would be surprised you'll be getting "enough attention" :)... The xs vs. xsd use for namespace aliasing is not relevant: the namespaces seem to be correctly used, if anything the xsd prefix seems superfluous in the given snippet. I would suggest to update your question with additional info; maybe an XML fragment, a description of how that translate to "individual property" and what would be in fact the list of typed members - basically some code. More of the WSDL would be beneficial... somehow I suspect your SOAP binding is RPC here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ZSI documentation:

If the operation invoked returns a ComplexType, typecode information must be provided in order to tell ZSI how to deserialize the response.

In order for ZSI to transparently deserialize the returned complex type into a Person instance, a module defining the class and its typecode must be appended to the ZSI.Path list. It is also possible to explicitly tell ZSI what class and typecode to use by passing the class as a parameter to the Binding.Receive() method. The first method is often preferred, particularly for publically-distributed libraries.

Code Generation from WSDL and XML Schema is the second way ZSI provides to access WSDL services. Given the path to a WSDL service, two files are generated, a 'service' file and a 'types' file, that one can then use to access the service.

Comment: user, not had a chance to follow up on this in code yet but your comment seems to provide hope.. thanks!

Comment: It's the best way on almost every SOAP framework. Use WSDL to generate strong typed classes and make the framework to transform the XML response into that classes.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you've not provided enough information for the real issue at hand, I will base this on the basis of you been a *newb*, and therefore wrap my answer around portions I find relevant to your question.

Your main web service is described in the WSDL **http://myserver:8181/soap/SoapTest?wsdl**, which holds an import to a parent WSDL. This parent WSDL holds service definitions which can be bind by your main service.

> Seems promising. A request to the import location
>   SoapTest?wsdl=SoapTest.wsdl returns: 
>   ..

From the document definition provided above, the import:

```
<wsdl:import location="http://myserver:8181/soap/SoapTest?wsdl=SoapTest.wsdl"
          namespace="http://webservices.mycompany.com">
</wsdl:import>
```

injects the parent *WSDL* file which holds the schema defintion for all elements and attributes relevant for your service. Meaning a standalone call to it, will reveal the `xs` namespace definition. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_intro.asp) for more on schema and datatypes.

> HUH.. upon review, I see xs being used as a namespace but xmlns:xsd
>   defined?? How might this happen?

Yes, the schema is defined not as a separate file, but as part of the *WSDL*. It is defined between `<wsdl:types>` tags:

```
 <wsdl:types>
       <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://webservices.mycompany.com" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://webservices.mycompany.com" version="1.0">
   [..]
 </wsdl:types>
```

See [here](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/zsi.html) also for more on ZSI binding and stub generation.

Comment: Bitmap, thanks for your clarifications.  I'll have a further look at teh ZSI docs; seems to me it's the binding portions that aren't working.